# SpringTemplate no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I am getting the following error while using spring rest template but i have defined jackson for json responses.

As well when I query to the url with rest client i get a good response.

> ```
> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [tripadvisor.TripAdvisorResponse<java.util.List<model.external.tripadvisor.TripAdvisorLocation>>] and content type [text/javascript;charset=utf-8]
> at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:109)
> at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:812)
> at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:796)
> at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:576)
> at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:544)
> at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:495)
> at sync.service.location.LocationServiceImpl.syncTripAdvisorLocations(LocationServiceImpl.java:69)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
> at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
> at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:110)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

rest template configuration:

> ```
> @Bean
> public ClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory() {
>     return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient());
> }
> @Bean
> public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
>     RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(httpRequestFactory());
>     List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
>     for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
>         if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
>             MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter;
>             jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
>         }
>     }
>     return restTemplate;
> }
> @Bean
> public HttpClient httpClient() {
>     PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
>     CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(connectionManager).build();
>     connectionManager.setMaxTotal(DEFAULT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS);
>     connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(DEFAULT_MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE);
>     connectionManager.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(new HttpHost("facebook.com")), 20);
>     connectionManager.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(new HttpHost("twitter.com")), 20);
>     connectionManager.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(new HttpHost("linkedin.com")), 20);
>     connectionManager.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(new HttpHost("viadeo.com")), 20);
>     connectionManager.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(new HttpHost("api.tripadvisor.com")), 20);
>     return closeableHttpClient;
> }
> ```

Comment: What Jackson version are you using? Have you checked that bean, that your if statement was reached?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Default media type for MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverters is

```
/**
 * Construct a new {@code BindingJacksonHttpMessageConverter}.
 */
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    super(new MediaType("application", "json", DEFAULT_CHARSET));
}
```

You can specify media type for MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter in your bean definition, like this

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(httpRequestFactory());
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
    for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
        if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter;
            jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
            jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(ImmutableList.of(new MediaType("application", "json", MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.DEFAULT_CHARSET), new MediaType("text", "javascript", MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.DEFAULT_CHARSET)));
        }
    }
    return restTemplate;
}
```

or using wildcard

```
jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(ImmutableList.of(new MediaType("*", "json", MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.DEFAULT_CHARSET), new MediaType("*", "javascript", MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.DEFAULT_CHARSET)));
```

Comment: Detailed and precise answer. Thank you