# How to parse correctly json data with RestTemplates and FasterXml-Jackson?

Tags: java, json, spring

I have this json string:
{"status":"OK","copyright":"Copyright (c) 2016 The New York Times Company. All Rights Reserved.","section":"home","last_updated":"2016-03-30T16:02:01-05:00","num_results":19,"results":[{"section":"Health", ... }]

And I only need the results, which are the top stories from New York Times.

Here is my TopStory.class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TopStory {

    private String title;
    @JsonProperty("abstract")
    private String storyAbstract;
    private String url;
    private String section;
    private String published_date;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getStoryAbstract() {
        return storyAbstract;
    }

    public void setStoryAbstract(String storyAbstract) {
        this.storyAbstract = storyAbstract;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public void setSection(String section) {
        this.section = section;
    }

    public String getPublished_date() {
        return published_date;
    }

    public void setPublished_date(String published_date) {
        this.published_date = published_date;
    }

    public TopStory(String title, String storyAbstract, String url, String section, String published_date) {

        this.title = title;
        this.storyAbstract = storyAbstract;
        this.url = url;
        this.section = section;
        this.published_date = published_date;
    }
}
```

And here is my TopStories.class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TopStories {

    @JsonProperty("results")
    private ArrayList<TopStory> stories;

    public TopStories(ArrayList<TopStory> stories) {
        this.stories = stories;
    }

    public ArrayList<TopStory> getStories() {
        return stories;
    }

    public void setStories(ArrayList<TopStory> stories) {
        this.stories = stories;
    }
}
```

This is the code I use in the main class:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
ArrayList<TopStory> topStories=restTemplate.getForObject(url,TopStories.class).getStories();
```

I keep getting this exception. How can I fix this?

```
    org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class TopStories] and content type [text/json]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

First, the error message says that the media type coming back is `text/json`. By default, `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` only converts `application/json` and `application/*+json`. You will need to configure it to also convert `text/json`.

For example, the following code could work:

```java
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    //compiler issue has been resolved.
jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("text", "json", MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.DEFAULT_CHARSET)));
    
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(jsonConverter);
```

Second, I believe you need a default constructor for `TopStory` and `TopStories` for Jackson to initially instantiate the objects.

Reference [SpringTemplate no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131139/springtemplate-no-suitable-httpmessageconverter-found-for-response-type) for some additional detail.